# 1 Presenter for multiple tabs (fragments), OR each tab should have presenter?

Tags: android, code-cleanup, directory-structure, clean-architecture

As the title says, I have a view with multiple tabs, (Library for example):

- Book List Tab (`BookListFragment`)
- Borrowed History Tab (`BorrowedBooksFragment`)
- Recommended Books Tab (`RecommendedBooksFragment`)

Should I have 1 `presenter` for the view that holds all the tab (`LibraryTabFragment` with `LibraryPresenter`) OR should I have `Presenter` for each tab? (`BookListPresenter`, `BorrowedBooksPresenter`, `RecommendedBooksPresenter`)

And why? in terms of flexibility and scalability. As for now, we have different presenters for each tabs, but it looks messy because there's so many folders with books as prefix (booklist, bookrecommended, bookhistory). But if I merge all in 1 presenter, I feel like it is not that scalable (or not?). Any insights or advice? Thank you.

Comment: I would personally use 1 Presenter > 1 Book Repository > Multiple Datasource (Local Db, Network) for this scenario.

Comment: I do have 1 book repository and multiple data source, but I'm confused on the view part, in which should I use 1 or multiple presenters. Thanks for your input, will wait for more, an explanation also will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: All those 3 Fragments share a common trait specifically the `Book` label so having 1 Presenter that manage those 3 Views or 3 Fragments is a lot meaningful personally. Also you get some little performance benefit upon having single Presenter.

Comment: Noted on this, thank you very much.

Comment: I think this question is not specific to Uncle Bob's clean architecture but not to SRP. Following that u should probably have one presenter per fragment.

Comment: you can check my [realization](https://github.com/Devit951/Mediateka) of clean architecture